# Writing an elegant Click Handler

Tags: java, android, gwt

We usually write a click handler on a button (in GWT or Swing or Android) in the following way (**way 1**).

```
class A {

    public void myMethod() {

        int count = 0 ;

        Button myButton = new Button("x");
        myButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
          public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
              count = 1 ;
          }

        });

    }
}
```

However, we can also write a different class for the click handler and implement it like the following (**way 2**) :

```
class A implements ButtonClickInterface {

    int count ;
    public void myMethod() {

        count = 0 ;

        Button myButton = new Button("x");
        myButton.addClickHandler(new MyClickHander(this));

    }

    @Override
    public void buttonClicked() {
        count = 1 ;        
    }
}

interface ButtonClickInterface {
    public void buttonClicked() ;
}

class MyClickHandler implements ClickHandler {


    ButtonClickInterface buttonClickInterface ;

    public MyClickHandler(ButtonClickInterface buttonClickInterface) {
        this.buttonClickInterface = buttonClickInterface ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        buttonClickInterface.buttonClicked() ;         
    }

}
```

Here I have to make `count` as a class variable. Can this have any drawbacks? Also can the above way of implementation have any other drawbacks? How would the two ways in which I have implemented the ClickHandler face off against each other in terms of complexity, coupling, number of objects created and code readability ?

Comment: Your first snippet won't work as-is: `count` would need to be `final` to be accessible to the `ClickHandler`, and thus would be read-only. you'd need an `int[1]` or some other _holder_ (`AtomicInteger` could be used in Swing or Android –not GWT–). That changes the complexity of the snippet, so you might want to reconsider your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second solution is way too complex.

I often do that on Android (pseudocode):

```
class A implements OnClickListener {

    onCreate() {
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.myButtonId:
                // do something
                break;
            // more cases
            default: 
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "not implemented");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say that you can't do this with a switch statement anymore, android no longer sets R.id.xxx to final so you are forced to use if...else if...else instead.

Comment: Only in library projects! (just tested to make sure...)

Comment: Ah cool, it was a library project that flagged this for me so it's good to know.

Comment: Don't you know about `android:onClick` attribute and event declaration in class with the same name?

Comment: I do, but I don't like to mix layout and code more than necessary. And giving the method name in the onClick attribute is a mix up.

Answer (score 5):

You can also define your clickHandler in xml.

put this in your Activity class:

```
public void myClickEvent(View view) {
    //Do something
}
```

and put this in your layout .xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/myId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:onClick="myClickEvent"/>
```

Comment: +1 I would suggest this as well. Less code and more optimization.

Answer (score 2):

When the click handler is used only for a single button in one place then I would rather go for

```
Button myButton = new Button("x");
myButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
          public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
              count = 1 ;
          }

});
```

Having the click handler in a separate class is IMO only useful when the handler can be reused by other controls.
As to your question, I usually go for options `1`. Option `2` is way too complex and introduces yet another indirection which is not really needed.

Comment: What if i have many buttons (say 6 on a page) in my web app/Android application?

Comment: I just hate that way of putting the code in the object instantiation... Most unmaintainable and not reusable thing ever.

Comment: @AceMcCloud As I mentioned, if you want to reuse the event handler then move it to a separate class

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes it is not reusable that's why I said if you want reuse then go for a full blown handler class :)

Comment: If you have 6 buttons you make a method `public void addHandler(Button btn){ btn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){... )}` and then call every button with it `addHandler(yourButton)`

Answer (score 2):

With GWT and using UiBinder, you also have the solution to use a `@UiHandler` method:

```
@UiField Button myButton; // will be injected by UiBinder

@UiHandler("myButton") // will be bound to my Button as ClickHandler by UiBinder
void incrementClick(ClickEvent event) {
  count += 1;
}
```